# USB OTG on Compute Module 3

Tags: usb, raspbian-stretch, compute-module, otg

Has anyone ever tried configuring the USB of the Compute Module 3 as USB OTG?
In the default kernel (Raspbian Stretch - Kernel7), support for usb otg appears to be disabled.
Has anyone managed to recompile the kernel and test if it works?

The Raspbian guys seem to forget about the usb otg of compute module 3.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't own a Compute Module 3, but am curious as to what you mean by support for OTG appearing disabled in the kernel. `kernel7.img` has support for OTG but it's disabled in the device tree block even for Pi Zero/Pi Zero W, only to be enabled with a device tree overlay via `dtoverlay=dwc2`. You're saying that same overlay doesn't work for Compute Module 3? Feel free to edit your question with kernel/devicetree code snippets and all to clarify.

Comment: It worked for me following [this](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41) guide

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet

**9.4 USB**

*The BCM2837 USB port is On-The-Go (OTG) capable. If using either as a fixed slave or fixed master, please tie the USB_OTGID pin to ground.*

*The USB port (Pins USBDP and USBDM) must be routed as 90 ohm differential PCB traces.*

*Note that the port is capable of being used as a true OTG port however there is no official documentation.Some users have had success making this work.*

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/datasheets/rpi_DATA_CM3plus_1p0.pdf